# Identity for inverse of sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

We have to show that for invertible m x m matrices A and n x n matrices C, as well as arbitrary n x m matrix B, the following identity holds:

$(A^{-1}+B^T C^{-1} B)^{-1}B^TC^{-1} = AB^T(BAB^T+C)^{-1}$

I know that in general the equality $A^{-1}+B^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}$ does **not** hold, and I see that $B^T C^{-1} B$ is an m x m matrix - but how can I continue from here?
Hints welcome, please do not solve it fully:-)

Comment: Woodbury formula

Comment: good to know that the "awful" formula as called below is having a name:) thx! reading it up

Comment: it's not the prettiest formula I have ever seen :) but its awfulness should not prevent it to have a name, glad to learn it too

Comment: fyi, we are looking at it in the context of kernel methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice what you get when you multiply your equality on both side by $A^{-1}+B^TC^{-1}B$ on the left and by $BAB^T+C$ on the right. You should obtain a trivial identity. From this point you can go back and prove your (awful) formula. Of course we have to suppose that $A^{-1}+B^TC^{-1}B$ and $BAB^T+C$ are indeed invertible matrices.

Comment: That was almost the solution in fact!:) I get the identity $B^T C^{-1}B A B^T + B^T = B^T + B^T C^{-1}B A B^T$. Thank you